# WP_Query (list) posts according to author's custom field

Tags: wp-query, author

I'm trying to work out or even find a way to list all the posts according to a custom field of the authors. I'm using WP User Frontend Pro and the plugin allows me to create custom fields for the user/author registration page.

e.g. All the schools need to register and choose which years they teach. So I want to list all the posts by those schools that teach specific years.

If I was talking about WP_Query for custom fields assigned to posts then that'd be easy as below, but how do I do this for an author's custom field?

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => array( 'post' ),
    'meta_query'             => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'school_year',
            'compare'   => '=',
            'type'      => 'CHAR',
        ),
    ),
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // do something
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: [`WP_User_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) works much like `WP_Query`. It's not clear what you're trying to query for though- posts by users who have a specific value in user meta?

Comment: Not clear? I'm trying list all the posts, with authors that have a specific value in user meta. I don't want to list the authors, I want to list the posts that's why I thought WP_Query would be best.

Comment: `WP_Query` can't do that. You need to query for authors, then query for each author's posts.

Comment: @Milo have you seen any sort of example that had those two elements put together?